# Risk of committing IdentityFile name for OpenSSH configuration to public repository

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, openssh, git

What is the risk of committing the `IdentityFile` line for each of my `Host` entries in my `~/.ssh/config` to my public dotfiles repository? Would providing such information make it any easier for an attacker to compromise those keys?

```
cat ~/.ssh/config
Host SE
  Hostname security.stackexchange.com
  User rage
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/security_key
```

**Versus**

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Note: this is the default key name when invoking `ssh-keygen`.

Comment: If you committed all your private keys, then yes, that's a huge huge problem. If you only committed your ssh config, then no, they cannot do much with the information except see where you connect and know your username for each system. It might help with social engineering later.

Comment: No, not the actual keys themselves; just the names.

Comment: Then I'd say you're probably fine. If you want you can change your usernames but that's probably it; relying on the name and locations of your private keys is security through obscurity and shouldn't be trusted anyway.